# jQuery toggle between two ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does the following code not work? The red square becomes green but on a second click doesn't become red again.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#red").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "green");
  });

  $("#green").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">
```

See also: https://codepen.io/thomasmalley/pen/OqWNaM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because you assign the event handler on load, before the `#green` element exists.

To fix this you need to use delegated event handlers so that the element selector is evaluated when the event occurs:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', "#red", function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "green");
  });

  $(document).on('click', "#green", function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red"></div>
```

*That being said*, it's not great practice to be changing `id` attributes at runtime. They should be static. A much better idea would be to toggle a `class` on the element instead, which governs the styling.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#foo').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
#foo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#foo.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Man you're really fast :)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is `div` with id `red` and after clicking that div it switches id to `green` that is dynamically so in this case we use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Try below code -

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".parent").on('click', '#red', function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "green");
  });

  $(".parent").on('click', '#green', function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div id="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Relies almost exclusively on off-site content for an explanation. A small excerpt from the linked page about _why_ event-delegation is needed would improve this answer imo. "_Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, **whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.**_"

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing my answer. @Lewis

Comment: The Combination of Explanation & [Link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for further in depth Information helped me very much!

Comment: My pleasure :) @thomasmalley

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you load the page there is no element with the id `green` for a click event to be added to.

Instead, you can use event delegation by using:

```
$(document).on('click', '#red', function() {...}
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', '#green', function() {...}
```

This way, your click event will be applied to the element with the id `green`.

See working example below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#red', function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "green");
  });

   $(document).on('click', '#green', function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the id is added dynamically, the code `$("#green").click(function() {` when loaded will not find element with id `green` so the click event is not set for that element. Thus you can add a listener on document level:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'div', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id === 'red'){
      $(this).attr("id", "green");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("id", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">
```

Answer (score 0):

change script

```
 $(document).on('click','#red',function() {
    $('#red').attr("id", "green");
  });

  $(document).on('click','#green',function() {
    $('#green').attr("id", "red");
  });
```